# How to test that a job is released after a certain time when failing?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

When I have a job like this

```php
class CheckVideoStatusJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $video;

    public function __construct(Video $video)
    {
        $this->video = $video;
    }

    public function handle(CheckStatusAction $action)
    {
        if (! $action->execute($this->video)) {
            $this->release(60);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I test: when the job has failed it will be released back to the queue after (60) seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you rely on Laravels own tests to secure release method works and in a work environment not use time testing this. If you still want to, you just need to be sure that release is called. I would do a partial mock using [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#partial-test-doubles).

This code creates a class that only mocks the release method and pass the video to the constructor.

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock(CheckVideoStatusJob::class, $video)->makePartial();

// expects release call, once, parameter should be 60 returns null
$mock->shouldReceive('release')->once()->with(60)->return(null);

// action should offcourse secure that execute returns false
$mock->handle($action);
```

For securing the tests use assertions with mockery use the mockery trait.

```
use MockeryPHPUnitIntegration;
```

Comment: For now i'm not certain this would work, due to when the handle method is called it is to the parent class and questioning what $this->release will do from there, will test it tonight, leaving the answer as it may can help until then

Comment: Based on this answer the solution should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666043/mock-method-from-the-same-class-that-tested-method-is-using

Comment: I like it and it does makes sense to use this approach. A related question I don't want to put it in a new post. I am using "retryUntil" function (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#time-based-attempts), how can I test it with this approach?

Comment: $mock->shouldReceive('retryUntil')->once()->with()->return(null); should do the trick